# Is it possible to run scanf like this?

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,i,b,c,d,e;        
    array[5]["b","c","d","e"]; // defining input characters as int


    for(i=1;i<=a;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<=a;j++)
        {
            printf("Input number %d ",i);
            scanf("%d",&array[j]);   // every loop it goes diffrent valuable
        }
    }

    printf("Your numbers %d"b,c,d,e,);
    return 0;
}
```

> I made some changes with your comment.
>       I want to assign each of numbers to different variable.

Comment: The program has undefined behavior.

Comment: Why do it like that when you can use an array?

Comment: This is not how variables work. Look up *arrays*.

Comment: array[5]["a","b","c","d","e"] 

array[j] // in the scanf ? and loop it

Comment: Please read a book on C. If you still have questions, post code written in valid C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
int main() {

    int numList[5];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("Input number %d ",i);
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    printf("Your numbers: ");
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         printf("%d, ",a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The method that I used for printing is quick and arbitrary, but you could also use:

```
printf("Your numbers are: %d,%d,%d,%d,%d.\n",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]);
```

to get the same result.

For the printf function: 1 %d means you need 1 integer listed after the quote, 2 for 2, and so on.

Definitely read up on arrays, they save so much time.

Also note that the second command in

> for(i=1;i=a;i++)

is assigning the value of a to i which is nonsensical.  This will also always result in the for loop contents being run, unless it fails due to not being initialized as Filipe Gonçalves pointed out.

Comment: I would upvote your answer if it weren't for 2 little technical mistakes. First, you want `scanf("%d", &a[i]);` (note the address-of operator usage in the second argument to `scanf()`). Second, `for(i=1;i=a;i++)` is just UB, since `a` has never been initialized - so, to be accurate, you can't say the loop will always run - it's UB, anything can happen.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections.  An edit has been made.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int **x;
    int i, a, b, c, d, e;
    int *vars[] = {&b, &c, &d, &e, &a};
    x = vars;
    for(x = vars; *x != &a; x++){
        scanf("%d", *x);
    }
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", b, c, d, e);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solutions . I cannont give reputation  :)